# Getting "permission denied for name" while trying to access mailmanager from the Vtiger CRM UI

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I am trying to access the Emails module from the CRM and whenever I try accessing the MailManager from the menu I get this error "Permission to perform the operation is denied for name: mailmanager".

I looked up the problem and it usually surfaces when trying to use the webservice and I've tried the suggested fix for that problem by checking the vtiger_ws_entitity table and there was an entry for Emails, so I tried adding one for MailManager but when I retry accessing the module I get handler not found, which is normal as there is no folder in /modules called MailManager.

The Emails show correctly through the related list from an Account but I couldn't access the list of all Emails.
[image: Emails Related List]

I tried creating a new role with all the rights + admin checkbox on for the user using it but I still got the same error.

Any clue on how to solve this? Knowing that I am trying to access trough the UI and not webservice, in fact using the webservice I can query the Emails entity just fine.

Vtiger version: 7.4 (self-hosted)

Original [question](https://discussions.vtiger.com/discussion/201847/getting-permission-denied-for-name-while-trying-to-access-mailmanager-from-the-ui/p1?new=1) in vtiger forum.